# Modified Extension of OrderBy to also handle ThenBy

Tags: c#

I have this extension that handles `OrderBy` together with a bool of asc/desc and it works like a charm:

```
public static IOrderedEnumerable<TSource> OrderByWithDirection<TSource, TKey>
     (this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
      Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector,
      bool descending)
{
    return descending ? source.OrderByDescending(keySelector)
                      : source.OrderBy(keySelector);
}

public static IOrderedQueryable<TSource> OrderByWithDirection<TSource, TKey>
    (this IQueryable<TSource> source,
     Expression<Func<TSource, TKey>> keySelector,
     bool descending)
{
    return descending ? source.OrderByDescending(keySelector)
                      : source.OrderBy(keySelector);
}
```

but I also need it to handle `ThenBy` (together with a bool of asc/desc)

The current syntax is:

```
bool primaryDescending = false;
var sortedList = unSortedList
    .OrderByWithDirection(o => o.primary, primaryDescending)
    .ToList();
```

What I would like is for the extension to handle something like this syntax:

```
bool primaryDescending = false;
bool secondaryDescending = true;
var sortedList = unSortedList
    .OrderByWithDirection(o => o.primary, primaryDescending)
    .ThenByWithDirection(o => o.secondary, secondaryDescending)
    .ToList();
```

Any tips on how to do this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: Since your `OrderBy` just returns an `IOrderedEnumerable` why can't you make exactly the same for `ThenBy` that accepts an `IOrderedEnumerable`?

Comment: There's already a Linq function for .ThenBy(). There's also functions for OrderyByDescending() and ThenByDescending() so there's no need to build what you're trying to do.

Comment: @chris-crush-code The standard Linq extension methods don't let you specify direction as a parameter.

Comment: It's still unnecessary since all your extension method does is interrogate the parameter then call the proper function, you could move that to outside the call and do away with the extension...

Comment: @chris-crush-code It isn't "unnecessary" - extension-methods like these are absolutely necessary if you need to dynamically build-up a query expression at runtime without having to fight the worst parts of "fluent"/method-chaining syntax (as C# does not provide a built-in way to branch while inside a chained method call). Without using this approach the number of lines of C# needed to express the same thing effectively triples.

Comment: As Dai says, the reason for this extension is to be able to pass a parameter and to dynamically sort a list. Sure I could to a massive IF-soup with the existing methods, but... let's simply not do that. : )

Comment: @Aluan Haddad, I'm sorry if it looked like I hadn't tried anything. I have tried A LOT, and usually don't post questions.

Comment: @Jippie well Dai provided the proper answer. It's often helpful to look at the .NET framework APIs for inspiration for this sort of thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to define `IOrderedQueryable.ThenByWithDirection` such that it calls `ThenBy___` instead of `OrderBy___`:

```
public static IOrderedEnumerable<TSource> ThenByWithDirection<TSource, TKey>
     (this IOrderedEnumerable<TSource> source,
      Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector,
      bool descending)
{
    return descending ? source.ThenByDescending(keySelector)
                      : source.ThenBy(keySelector);
}

public static IOrderedQueryable<TSource> ThenByWithDirection<TSource, TKey>
    (this IOrderedQueryable<TSource> source,
     Expression<Func<TSource, TKey>> keySelector,
     bool descending)
{
    return descending ? source.ThenByDescending(keySelector)
                      : source.ThenBy(keySelector);
}
```

Comment: Oh that's frustrating, I tried that but when I went from source I could only choose OrderBy. Meaning I had to do an OrderBy first and then follow it with a ThenBy.

Comment: @Jippie Correct. `ThenBy` can only be used after `OrderBy`. Look at the return-type: `IOrderedQueryable<T>` instead of `IQueryable<T>`.

Comment: Wonderful! Thank you very much for the answer and explenation!